# How to copy data from one column to another column(separate list) while adding the item using EventReceiver?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, development, custom-list, event-receivers, splistitem

I have created a sharepoint list named "test" in that I have a column URL as multiline text.While inserting data into that column need to update the same value in another list. I tried by adding event receiver

```
public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)  
{  
    base.ItemAdded(properties);  
    using (SPWeb web = properties.OpenWeb())  
    {  
        try  
        {  
            SPListItem currentItem = properties.ListItem;  
           /* some code to get values */
            currentItem.Update();  
        }  
        catch (Exception ex)  
        {  
            throw ex;  
        }  
    }
```

It's not working, Please suggest some idea achieve this.

Comment: Do you tried to change the Elements.xml and replace<!--<Receivers ListTemplateId="101">-->  to your List URL   <Receivers ListUrl="Lists/test">

Answer (score 1):

**First,** in case you need to run your event receive on a specific List, so you should modify `Elements.xml` to use `ListUrl` instead of  `ListTemplateId` as the following

```
<Receivers ListTemplateId="101">
```

to

```
<Receivers ListUrl="Lists/test">
```

Where the `Lists/test` is the List URL

---

**Second,** try to use the below code to

```
public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)  
{ 
   base.ItemAdded(properties);  
    using (SPWeb web = properties.OpenWeb())  
    {  
        try  
        {  
            // get the current List item            
            SPListItem currentItem = properties.ListItem; 
            // Second list
            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
            SPList List2 = web.Lists.TryGetList("destlist");
            SPListItem newItem = List2.Items.GetItemById(ID);
            newItem["FieldName"] = currentItem["FieldName"];
            newItem.Update();  
        }  
        catch (Exception ex)  
        {  
            throw ex;  
        }  
    } 
}
```

> **Note:** in case you don't know the corresponsind item ID, you can get the
>   List item via CAML at SPQuery, check the details at another thread at
>   [How to check if list item already exists? C# Sharepoint 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/200608/how-to-check-if-list-item-already-exists-c-sharepoint-2013)