# Extract document name and store them in separate document library columns

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow

I have been tasked to extract the document name and store them in 4 separate columns in SharePoint. The new documents which are .PDF's are named as such : Sam; Smith; 123456; Dental

And the column names on the list after stripping the document name are like below. 
*FName: Sam  
  *LName:Smith    
   *Employee number: 123456   
    *Record Type:Dental
[image]
So, I have created the document library list and added the above 4 columns to document library. From link [2](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/249666/extract-the-name-of-the-uploaded-file-in-document-library-into-another-column)   I understand that a workflow using MS Flow is a possible solution but the example they deal with has just one "-" and the documents i am dealing with has two ";". So i am really not sure how to come up with the sub-string expressions that they talk about.

Thank you for all your help and feedback. 
Sam

Answer (score 0):

You can split the filename using a SharePoint 2013 style workflow:

[image]

The actions used are:

- Set Workflow Variable
- Find Substring in String
- Do Calculation
- Extract Substring from Start of String
- Extract Substring from Index of String
- Set Field in Current Item

The result:

[image]

Comment: Hi Mike i cant thank you enough. Our HR team would like to convey their gratitude as well since it helped us save a bunch of time in typing out the fields individually. I was able to recreate your work to fit my list. Full disclosure - i am still trying to understand the exact logic in your steps since i am new to SPD workflows and I will get back to you if I have any questions.